# Send javascript to Chromium or Firefox from linux terminal

Tags: linux, shell-script, terminal, browser, javascript

I am using either a chromium or firefox web browser in kiosk mode to log in to a website from boot up, and I want to use a javascript to send in a command to login to a website automatically. I know how to write the javascript, but I do not know how to "pipe" the javascript into the web browser from a terminal bash file. Also, I am working in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

In OS X you can use AppleScript to run JavaScript in Chrome:

`xj(){ osascript -e'on run{a}' -e'tell app"google chrome"to tell active tab of window 1 to execute javascript a' -eend "$1"; }`

Firefox does not support AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Firefox is capable of doing what you want here even though there are [lots of command line options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-app_.2Fpath.2Fto.2Fapplication.ini) for launching Firefox from a script.

Chrome has [even more options](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) and may be able to pull off executing javascript from a local source, but I doubt it.

If you could somehow pass javascript in through the developer console then you could definitely execute arbitrary code in a web browser session (i.e. an automated login or what not).

### A Hack

Since you can definitely specify a starting url from a script for both browsers, perhaps the following will work <sub>1</sub>:

1. Write a script that automatically navigates to the web page that you want to login to and completes the login process, (i.e. `POST` the login form, whatever).
2. Save this file to your disk and make sure that the user can read it.
3. Launch Firefox and point it to this file:

   ```
    ./firefox -url "file:///home/thisUser/desktop/foo.html"
   ```

I am not sure that the url scheme `file:///` will work in all situations but I did test it on OSX.

This should load the file and try to render the content. The `file:///` thing is just a way not to have to run a web server on localhost, but that could work too.

You might run into XSS problems or other obstacles to doing a remote login so you may have to revert to a server side script and just point the browser at a `localhost` web server.

Best of luck!

<sup>1</sup> I haven't tested this all the way just tossing out an idea.